# Why can't I import folium python package?

Tags: python, directory, pip, folium

I've pip installed folium and get this error when I try to import it in when Im working in my home directory:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-af6e4f19ef00> in <module>()
----> 1 import folium

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/folium-0.3.0.dev0-      py2.7.egg/folium/__init__.py in <module>()
       3 from __future__ import absolute_import
       4 
 ----> 5 from folium.folium import Map, initialize_notebook, CircleMarker
       6 
       7 from folium.map import (FeatureGroup, FitBounds, Icon, LayerControl, Marker,

  //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/folium-0.3.0.dev0-  py2.7.egg/folium/folium.py in <module>()
       13 import json
       14 
  ---> 15 from branca.colormap import StepColormap
       16 from branca.utilities import color_brewer
      17 from branca.six import text_type, binary_type

 ImportError: No module named branca.colormap
```

However, i can import it when I cd to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages.... What gives?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Is `'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages'` in `sys.path`?

Answer (score 5):

Did you install the package with Anaconda? It looks like it's reading the package from Anaconda python's package install locations. A few things to try:

- `conda install branca`
- `pip install branca`