# Anaconda | New environment - Importing folium throws error

Tags: python, anaconda, folium

I have created a new environment as suggested in :
[Cannot create a new environment or install libraries in Ananconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59521175/cannot-create-a-new-environment-or-install-libraries-in-ananconda/59535555#59535555)

I have successfully installed `folium`, `geopandas` libraries

I'm trying to import them into my Jupyter Notebook which throws an error, I also tried installing as this suggested

[Why can't I import folium python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835374/why-cant-i-import-folium-python-package)

But it did not work for me

1) How to make sure that the Jupyter Notebook is using the new environment
2) How to fix this issue

Comment: Please can you show the error/traceback?  Thinking about it, have you installed folium first using the terminal in Jupyter?

Comment: You haven't answered so I don't know how urgent your question really is; without more information on what error it is giving it's hard to help.  However when I had a similar issue, I found if I opened a terminal in Jupyter and just typed "install folium", then navigated back to the Jupyter python window and used "import folium", it worked.  In summary, it isn't always enough to just install the packages in Anaconda.